# Unicode exception in Django template

Tags: python, django, unicode, django-templates, django-views

I have Django application that has unicode characters read from DB and they to be displayed as it is on the template.

here is what i tried in views and my template:

**views.py**:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from .models import keywords as m
def newdata(request):

    keywords = m.objects.all()
    template = loader.get_template('keywords.html')
    context = Context({
        'keywords': keywords,
           })
    #return HttpResponse(template.render(context))

    #return HttpResponse(meanings)
    return render(request, 'keywords.html',context)
```

I am trying to use the keywords from the database in a select list in my template using a js function like below,

**template**:

```
<html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</html>
        <select id="keyword1" name="keyword1" onChange="add_to_text1();">
          <option  value="" selected="selected">---SELECT---</option>
            {% for post in keywords %}
        <!-- here keyword has unicode strings -->
           <option value="{{post.id}}">{{post.keyword}}</option>
          {% endfor %}
        </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="key1" value='' id='key1'/> 


    function add_to_text1() {


        var e = document.getElementById("keyword1");
        var str = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
        var selected_keyword_id=e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        document.getElementById("key1").value = selected_keyword_id;

        "{% for each in keywords %}"
            var x="{{ each }}";
            var other_form=x.split(" - ")[0];
            var el=other_form+"({{ each.id }})"

            var opt = document.createElement('option');
            opt.value = "{{each.id}}";
            opt.innerHTML = el;
            select.appendChild(opt);



        "{% endfor %}"
    }
```

This is the error i get when i try to open the tempalte page

> Exception Value:   'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in
>   position 4: ordinal not in range(128) The string that could not be
>   encoded/decoded was: entrée - a

and error shown at

```
var x=" {{ each }}"
```

I tried adding coding: utf-8  in my views and similar config in template too upon many suggestions in other posts.

Still I am facing the issue. Can someone help me understand wht the issue is

Thanks

Update:

Using  `__unicode__` in model to return column values resolved the issue

Comment: Please show the full traceback, and the definition of the keywords model.

Comment: If your python version is 2.* then possibly you need to [use the python_2_unicode_compatible() decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/unicode/#choosing-between-str-and-unicode) on your keywords model.

Comment: Note that when you use `render`, you should use a regular dictionary `context = {'keywords': keywords}` instead of `Context({...})`.

Comment: what I don't understand is why are you passing django data to javascript and asking javascript to create HTML elements? You can do that direct with django templates!!